# How to find the row number in which button is clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table in which there is a button in the last column called issue. In each row, when I click the button I want it to call an ajax function that gets a certain value from the server. The value from the server will vary based on the row chosen. The current code I have is as follows

```
var $dntb = $("#dntb");
$dntb.on("focusin", function() {
        var i //have to get the row where the button is clicked 
        $("#iss" + i).click(function(event) {
        var sditmId = $("#sditm").val();
        var sdhedId = $("#sdhed").val();
        $.get('getstock', {
               sditmId: sditmId,
               sdhedId: sdhedId
        }, function(response) {
        $("#stk").val(response);
        });
        });
});
```

Please tell me how to find the value of 'i' in the above code, if this is wrong please tell me the correct method

The table is given below

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dntb">
                        <thead>
                        <th><strong>Sales Order Number</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Reference Order</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Order Item</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Transport Time</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Mode of Shipment</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Delivery Date</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Actions</strong></th>
                        </thead>
                        <jsp:useBean id="gen" scope="request" class="Common.General"/>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:set var="i" value="0"/>
                            <c:forEach items="${dlv.allDeliveryDetails}" var="row">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${row.sdhedIdDn}</td>
                                    <td>${row.sdhedDn}</td>
                                    <td>${row.sditmDn} - ${row.prdDn}</td>
                                    <td>${row.qtyDn}</td>
                                    <td>${row.trntmDn}</td>
                                    <td>${row.mshDn}</td>
                                    <td>${row.datDn}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="setData('${row.sdconDn}', '${row.sdhedIdDn}', '${row.sditmDn}', '${row.sdconIdDn}')" id="iss">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Issue
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <c:set var="i" value="${i+1}"/>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Nesting click event inside a focusin event is a really bad idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help u mate .. :)

Note:Jquery version >=1.7

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
        var rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        console.debug('Index', rowindex);
    });
```

**FYI**

[index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: Better would be to delegate it to TABLE level, not body imho

Answer (score 0):

try this.. ( use class instead id because id is unique )

```
$('table').on('click','button',function(){
    $( this ).closest('tr').find('.field1').val('bind value for field one.!');
    $( this ).closest('tr').find('.field2').val('bind value for field two.!');
});
```

u can also use

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $( this ).closest('tr').find('.field1').val('bind value for field one.!');
    $( this ).closest('tr').find('.field2').val('bind value for field two.!');
});
```

but click method won't work if your DOM inserted After Loading Page.

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/unav0j5g/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the button in table row and bind the button as shown below:-

```js
$(".btnClass").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr");
  // anything you want to do
  return false;
});
```